# Geometry data-type row in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, geometry

Is it possible somehow to return the data of the Geometry data-type in [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) using Model and not with `SQL`.
I have table in my DataBase with Geometry field and [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) always returns this filed as `NULL`.

Comment: I haven't used geometry fields with Cake, but it would probably be helpful to see how your table is set up, and how you are querying it with Cake.

Answer (score 0):

not out of the box.
i've modified `1.3.8` to support geometry columns for `mysql` and `postgres` though.
the changes are relatively small (`dbo_source/dbo_mysql/dbo_postgres`).
i'll work on `2.0.5` next and provide patches.